# How to use arrays in program (global) scope in OpenCL

Tags: memory-management, global-variables, constants, opencl

AMD OpenCL Programming Guide, Section 6.3 Constant Memory Optimization:

> Globally scoped constant arrays. These arrays are initialized,
>   globally scoped, and in the constant address space (as specified in
>   section 6.5.3 of the OpenCL specification). If the size of an array is
>   below 64 kB, it is placed in hardware constant buffers; otherwise, it
>   uses global memory. An example of this is a lookup table for math
>   functions.

I want to use this "globally scoped constant array". I have such code in pure C

```
#define SIZE 101
int *reciprocal_table;

int reciprocal(int number){
  return reciprocal_table[number];
}

void kernel(int *output)
{
  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i+)
    output[i] = reciprocal(i);
}
```

I want to port it into OpenCL

```
__kernel void kernel(__global int *output){
  int gid = get_global_id(0);

  output[gid] = reciprocal(gid);
}

int reciprocal(int number){
  return reciprocal_table[number];
}
```

What should I do with global variable `reciprocal_table`? If I try to add `__global` or `__constant` to it I get an error:

```
global variable must be declared in addrSpace constant
```

I don't want to pass `__constant int *reciprocal_table` from `kernel` to `reciprocal`. Is it possible to initialize global variable somehow? I know that I can write it down into code, but does other way exist?

P.S. I'm using AMD OpenCL

**UPD** Above code is just an example. I have real much more complex code with a lot of functions. So I want to make array in program scope to use it in all functions.

**UPD2** Changed example code and added citation from Programming Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define SIZE 2
int constant array[SIZE] = {0, 1};

kernel void
foo (global int* input,
     global int* output)
{
    const uint id = get_global_id (0);
    output[id] = input[id] + array[id];
}
```

I can get the above to compile with Intel as well as AMD. It also works without the initialization of the array but then you would not know what's in the array and since it's in the constant address space, you could not assign any values.

Program global variables have to be in the __constant address space, as stated by section 6.5.3 in the standard.

**UPDATE** Now, that I fully understood the question:

One thing that worked for me is to define the array in the constant space and then overwrite it by passing a kernel parameter `constant int* array` which overwrites the array.
**That produced correct results only on the GPU Device.** The AMD CPU Device and the Intel CPU Device did not overwrite the arrays address. It also is probably not compliant to the standard.

Here's how it looks:

```
#define SIZE 2
int constant foo[SIZE] = {100, 100};

int
baz (int i)
{
  return foo[i];
}

kernel void
bar (global int* input,
     global int* output,
     constant int* foo)
{
    const uint id = get_global_id (0);
    output[id] = input[id] + baz (id);
}
```

For input = {2, 3} and foo = {0, 1} this produces {2, 4} on my HD 7850 Device (Ubuntu 12.10, Catalyst 9.0.2). **But** on the CPU I get {102, 103} with either OCL Implementation (AMD, Intel). So I can not stress, how much I personally would NOT do this, because it's only a matter of time, before this breaks.

**Another way** to achieve this is would be to compute .h files with the host during runtime with the definition of the array (or predefine them) and pass them to the kernel upon compilation via a compiler option. This, of course, requires recompilation of the clProgram/clKernel for every different LUT.

Comment: Yes, i know. I want to initialize constant array from host. Is it true that the only way is write it down? Or I'm able to initialize it somehow different?

Comment: I changed example code and added citation from Programming Guide. Please look at question again. May be it is more understandable now.

Comment: Could you please give an example of first approach? I tried but failed in my way to overwrite array by passing parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to get this work in my own program some time ago.
I did not find any way to initialize a constant or global scope array from the host via some clEnqueueWriteBuffer or so. The only way is to write it explicitely in your .cl source file.

So here my trick to initialize it from the host is to use the fact that you are actually compiling your source from the host, which also means you can alter your src.cl file before compiling it.

First my src.cl file reads:

```
__constant double lookup[SIZE] = { LOOKUP };    // precomputed table (in constant memory).

double func(int idx) {
  return(lookup[idx])
}

__kernel void ker1(__global double *in, __global double *out)
{
   ... do something ...
   double t = func(i)
   ...
}
```

notice the lookup table is initialized with LOOKUP.

Then, in the host program, before compiling your OpenCL code:

- compute the values of my lookup table in host_values[]
- on your host, run something like:

  ```
  char *buf = (char*) malloc( 10000 );
  int count = sprintf(buf, "#define LOOKUP ");    // actual source generation !
  for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) count += sprintf(buf+count, "%g, ",host_values[i]);
  count += sprintf(buf+count,"\n");
  ```
- then read the content of your source file src.cl and place it right at buf+count.
- you now have a source file with an explicitely defined lookup table that you just computed from the host.
- compile your buffer with something like clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &buf, &src_sz, err);
- voilà !

Answer (score -1):

It looks like "array" is a look-up table of sorts. You'll need to clCreateBuffer and clEnqueueWriteBuffer so the GPU has a copy of it to use.

Comment: It is like example code. The main question is: how to initialize and use array program scope?

Comment: I changed example code and added citation from Programming Guide. Please look at question again. May be it is more understandable now.

Comment: @Dithermaster: this does not work. Or can you provide an example ?